# Deployed aspx page can't access methods from same project

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET with VB, and .NET version 3.5.  In the project, I've got some utility functions that I call from expressions in the aspx pages and also in code behind.  This all works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy to the production server, I get this compilation error on each of those utility methods:

```
BC30456: 'XXX' is not a member of 'String'.
```

where XXX is an extension method defined on System.String.  I'm baffled about this for a number of reasons:

1. Why is ASP.NET compiling anything at all, since I've precompiled the application and put everything in the bin directory.
2. ASP.NET knows the functions are there because they work in code behind.  It's only when used in the aspx page that I have this problem.  (e.g. if I do something like this: <%= "A string to XXX-ify".XXX())%>)
3. This method **is** public, which I verified with Reflector.
4. I imported the relevant namespaces in the web.config file, and I can see that these namespaces are being imported in the call that ASP.NET makes to the compiler.

What on earth is going on here?  I really need access to these utility functions because, well, they're really useful.

Comment: Did you deploy the dll with your extension methods? Which .net framework do you have on your production machine?

Comment: The extension methods are in the same dll as the web application, and that is deployed correctly AFAICT.  The framework is v3.5.

Comment: You said the method is public, what about the class it is in? Have you try to use the namespace in front of the method? Some like <%= myNamespace.MyStringMethod() %>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked more closely at one example, the function in question was a Friend (internal in c#), and the page can't see them.  So maybe I was hallucinating about the method being public.  Still, it's something to look out for.

I guess I don't fully understand the compilation system in ASP.NET, but maybe the page is compiled into a separate assembly from the code modules, and so such  functions must be public if you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .Net version of the site in IIS.

This may be set to a version that does not support extension methods.

Comment: It's running 3.5, which should be fine.  I guess I could do some testing to see if it would be able to see the same methods coded as non-extension methods.

Comment: Check the .net framework version on the application pool. Possible values are 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 and 4.0. Version 3.5 is just additions to 2.0.